# Errors implementing ProtobufJS in Cordova app

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, protocol-buffers

I'm writing a Cordova app and currently testing it on the android simular (x86 image).  I'm attempting to use [ProtobufJS](https://github.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js) to implement protocol buffers between the client app and my server.  I've verified using a javascript parser that all JS files are syntacticaly correct.  There are several ways to implement ProtobufJS.  The two ways I've settled on both create errors in the android log.

**Method 1: Using 'pbjs' to create a JS Class object out of the proto file.**

In my index.html file I have the following script tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Long.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ByteBuffer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ProtoBuf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ClientMessage.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/common.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
```

In my index.js file after onDeviceReady I call TestProtoObject() which is defined in common.js.  ClientMessage.js is the generated JS class file derived from my proto file.  Based on [this link](https://github.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js/issues/149) I should be able to reference the class via the package name defined in the proto like this:

```
function TestProtoObject()
{
    var blah = new ForeverRPG.ClientMessage();
}
```

Or via _root, I assume like this:

```
function TestProtoObject()
{
    var blah = new _root.ClientMessage();
}
```

However, that gives me the following errors:

```
I/chromium( 2114): [INFO:CONSOLE(169)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: Long is not defined", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/ByteBuffer.js (169)
I/chromium( 2114): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'newBuilder' of undefined", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/ClientMessage.js (1)

...

I/chromium( 2114): [INFO:CONSOLE(64)] "Received Event: deviceready", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js (64)
I/chromium( 2114): [INFO:CONSOLE(64)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: ForeverRPG is not defined", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/common.js (64)
```

"Long" is defined by Long.js but according to dcodeIO it is not required for ByteBuffer (which is required by ProtobufJS), however, if I remove the file I get undefined errors in ByteBuffer.js.  The last "not defined" error is because the ClientMessage.js fails to parse I'm guessing.

**Method 2: Using 'pbjs' to create JSON that I read in at runtime to create the class:**
Using the same setup as above except without the ClientMesssage.js I added a method in common.js that does the following:

```
var builder = ProtoBuf.newBuilder();
builder.define("ForeverRPG");
builder.create([
    {
        "package": "ForeverRPG",
        "messages": [
            {
        <JSON here: removed for brevity>
            }
        ]
    }
]);

ForeverRPG = builder.build("ForeverRPG");
```

However, that gives me this error:

```
I/chromium( 2357): [INFO:CONSOLE(64)] "Received Event: deviceready", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/index.js (64)
I/chromium( 2357): [INFO:CONSOLE(364)] "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function", source: file:///android_asset/www/js/ProtoBuf.js (364).
```

I'll provide the entire project link in the comments, SO won't let me have more than two links in my post due to my newb status.

Thanks for any help,

Dustycoder

Comment: Project link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwwdWWzdMmR6M2NzZkpBUWs4aXM/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dustycoder You have `package ForeverRPG;` defined in your `.proto` file, so, assuming you are using `-t=js` when compiling your protobuf, you should write:

```
var msg = new _root.ForeverRPG.ClientMessage();
/* Theese are wrong:
var blah = new ForeverRPG.ClientMessage();
var blah = new _root.ClientMessage();
*/
```

Comment: Here are the erros when the page loads:    
"Uncaught ReferenceError: Long is not defined", source: ByteBuffer.js (169)    
"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function", source: ProtoBuf.js (364)  
  
And the error when I try your line (occurs after page loads):  
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ForeverRPG' of undefined", source: common.js (74)

Comment: Ok, that means you are using `int64` in your protobufs, but you didn't include [Long.js lib](https://github.com/dcodeIO/Long.js) before trying to create your protobuf classes.